# allow access to specific subdir via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In the parent directory of my site I have in the `.htaccess`:

Options All -Indexes

Now in `parent_dir/images/uploaded/` I want to allow people to view this. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting another `.htaccess` into the directory in question saying

```
Options All +Indexes
```

should work.

Comment: @jason try `Options +Indexes`

Comment: @jason sorry, then I don't know what to do... It *could* be that the central server configuration is blocking the setting

Comment: ...stupid mistake on my end. this works perfectly. thanks for taking the time.